# std::fstream seems to read in different sizes

Tags: c++, file, byte, fstream

I'm working on ubuntu 10.04 and a gcc. I have a binary file with my own magic number. When I read the file, the magic number is not the same. The streams seams to be correct.

Writing magic number :

```
std::fstream chfile;
chfile.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
if (chfile.good())
{
    chfile << (unsigned char)0x02 << (unsigned char)0x46 << (unsigned char)0x8A << (unsigned char)0xCE;
    // other input
    chfile.close();
}
```

Reading magic number :

```
std::fstream chfile;
chfile.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in);
if (chfile.good())
{
    unsigned char a,b,c,d;
    chfile >> a;
    chfile >> b;
    chfile >> c;
    chfile >> d;
    printlnn("header must : " << (int)0x02 << ' ' << (int)0x46 << ' ' << (int)0x8A << ' ' << (int)0xCE); // macro for debugging output
    printlnn("header read : " << (int)a << ' ' << (int)b << ' ' << (int)c << ' ' << (int)d);
    chfile.close();
}
```

When I use 02 46 8A CE as magic number it's alright (as the output says):

```
header must : 2 70 138 206
header read : 2 70 138 206
```

but when I use EA 50 0C C5 then the output is :

```
header must : 234 80 12 197
header read : 234 80 197 1
```

and the last 1 is a legit value for the next input. So why differ they and how do I fix this ?

Comment: There were no `fstream`s in STL, plus I highly doubt you're using it.

Comment: @Fanael Did I wrote STL's fstream ? In the Title it says std::fstream. If so, are there people, who are allowed to change the title ?

Comment: Yes, you did. See the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9469361/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, `operator>>` is skipping over the character value 12. `operator>>` recognizes `12` as whitespace, and skips it, searching for the next valid character.

Try using an unformatted input operation (like `chfile.read()` or `chfile.get()`) instead.

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens, I'm glad your experience on StackOverflow was positive. Please *upvote* each helpful answer (click on the upward-facing triangle), and *accept* the best answer (click on the check-mark.) Then go read other people's questions and answer them, if you can.

Comment: I'm just registered but I'm using stackoverflow since 3(?) years. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `<<` and `>>` with binary files, they are used for formatted reading and writing.
In particular, they do special handling of whitespace such as 0xC (i.e. formfeed), which makes them unsuitable for binary I/O.